# Get current factor level index from `tapply` in `FUN`

Tags: r, tapply

Using the `tapply` function, can I somehow have access to the "group"/"level"  of the factor it's currently operating on?

Example:

Average miles per gallon by cylinders:

```
ybar_j <- tapply(mtcars$mpg, as.factor(mtcars$cyl), mean)
```

Now I want to subtract the level mean for cars with x cylinders from each x-cylinder mileage.
Eg. for 4 cylinders:

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4, ]$mpg - ybar_j[1]
```

I can do it in a for-loop:

```
ybar_j_index <- as.numeric(names(ybar_j))
m <- length(ybar_j)

for(j in 1:m) { 
    # Relevant subset of observations at 'j' level. 
    mtcars_j <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl==ybar_j_index[j], ]

    (mtcars_j$mpg - ybar_j[j])

Can I do this without a for-loop?
```

Comment: `ave` gives a vector of the same length `ave(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, FUN = function(x) x - mean(x))`

Comment: A variant would be `with(mtcars, mpg - ave(mpg, cyl))`